# code . & exit in cmd terminal doesn't work as expected

Tags: windows, cmd, terminal, prompt

I would like to **open vscode in the cwd and exit the Windows cmd terminal from which the command is issued at the same time**.

`code .` (with a `.` for cwd) launches vscode in the cwd. `exit` closes the terminal. But as issuing the first command makes the terminal loses focus, I need to give it back to it to issue the second command.

I would like to type a **single line command that does both actions** at once, thus without the terminal losing its focus.

`code . & exit` doesn't work as the terminal window remains open and hangs infinitely with a flashing cursor. `Ctrl-C` doesn't bring the cmd prompt back and clicking the upper right **x** is the only way to close the terminal window when in that state. (vscode opens correctly in the cwd thought.)

How to do so?

Comment: There is no script. I just want to open **vscode** in the **cwd** of my **Windows cmd terminal** and **close** that terminal at the same time. `code .` is to launch vscode in the cwd, `exit` is to close the terminal. I would like to combine both commands (not having to close the cmd terminal manually once vscode is open).

Comment: Again: I want to enter those commands in a Windows command terminal after the command prompt. I don't know what to explain more... Thank you! I will wait for someone else that can understand me for his assistance.

Comment: Are you aware that doesn't sound very polite ?

Comment: Sorry but I tried to stay as polite as possible with [K J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10802527/k-j). But on his _deleted_ comments you could read he suggested I was not making myself understandable. After reformulating my issue, I didn't know what to do more besides hoping for assistance from someone else.

Comment: I agree I should have written instead: "Maybe somebody else knows how to help me?"

Answer (score 0):

`call code . & exit` does the trick!